# Transfer Data from Campaign Manager to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-transfer

My question is about how can I setup my Cloud storage bucket to retrieve data from my Campaign Manager account. I aim to process Camapaign report data in Big query, combining them with others data sources.
So in the documentation, it seems that it is possible with Transfert Data utility but I need before to store data files in a Cloud bucket and then it will be possible to use Data Transfer to get the data in BigQuery. 
So how can I get Campaign Manager Data in a Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already tried following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/doubleclick-campaign-transfer) to setup BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Campaign manager? In the [Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/doubleclick-campaign-transfer#before_you_begin) section you'll need to contact either your campaign manager reseller or the [campaign manager support](https://support.google.com/dcm/answer/2834170?hl=en&ref_topic=2834087&visit_id=1-636444821343154346-869320595&rd=1) to setup the Campaign Manager DTv2 files.

> After completing this step, you will receive a Cloud Storage bucket name similar to the following: dcdt_-dcm_account123456

After doing this, you may now complete the rest of the documentation.